# Getting started with Google Group APIs

Tags: eclipse, google-provisioning-api, google-groups-settings, google-admin-audit-api

Hi Everyone and thanks for reading.

I work in higher education and just recently inherited a Google Admin position from a leaving co worker. It turns out that we had a webpage that listed all of our different groups that used the old version of the Google API with gdata. Its broken now and I am wondering whats the best way to attack this issue is.

Here is what I have so far:
1) Eclipse Java EE
2) Google API Plugin.
3) Maven Plugin
4) Mercurial Plugin
5) A working test application that prints out strings and a cloud project with the group settings api enabled.
6) Oauth2.0 credentials.

My problem is I just don't know where to go from here. I need to basically create a web service that displays our Groups data for the entire domain (separated by Group ID). I have used GAM before and it was useful, but obviously not a long term solution for a Web Server based API.Does anyone have any kind of tutorial with pulling groups from a domain using Java? The documentation is spotty at best and every video I have watched is either out dated or uses very specific situations, none of which apply. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at some of the examples of using Apps Script?  There are a couple that examples of what you can do in this [post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/google-groups-and-google-apps-script.html)